# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'as_attachment' for reportlab django

Tags: django, python-2.7

Was following this here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/outputting-pdf/

The code from there above I have in my views.py

```
def test_report_lab(request):

  theBuffer = io.BytesIO()

  p=canvas.Canvas(theBuffer)

  p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello World")

  p.showPage()
  p.save()

  return FileResponse(theBuffer, as_attachment=True, filename='hello.pdf')
```

And got the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'as_attachment'
```

Not sure why, `FileResponse` should be totally happy with an as_attachment?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.FileResponse

Comment: Hmm might be the case that you put the `as_attachment` param in the wrong place. Mind posting your code so we can see?

Comment: I will edit the code but it is literally the same code as on the outputting-pdf, I have had a heck of a time with easy_pdf to getthings to work so was rewriting my invoicing system to use reportlab here and now hit this wall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature was added in Django 2.1. From the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/#requests-and-responses):

> **Requests and Responses**
>
> - [...]
> - The new **as_attachment** argument for [**FileResponse**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.FileResponse) sets the **Content-Disposition** header to make the browser ask if the user wants to download the file. **FileResponse** also tries to set the **Content-Type** and **Content-Length** headers where appropriate.

You are likely not using the correct django version. You can check which version you are using with [`pip freeze`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/).

To make the browser treat the response as an attachment in earlier Django versions you need to [manually set the `Content-Disposition` header](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#telling-the-browser-to-treat-the-response-as-a-file-attachment) on the response object:

```
response = FileResponse(theBuffer, content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="hello.pdf"'
return response
```

To avoid those kind of errors in the future make sure you have selected the correct documentation for the Django version you are using. You can select your version in the bottom right corner on every page of the docs.

Comment: If OP is using Python 2.7 as in the tags, then there is no way he can be using Django 2.1.

Comment: yah I just checked I am indeed using django 1.11.15

Comment: @Codejoy Then you can either update (which may need a relevant amount of refactoring if you are coming from python2.7 which is not supported by Django 2.1) or use the method described in my answer with previous versions of Django.

Comment: I found the older documentation and got up and running.